# Heroku Procfile command Java

Tags: java, heroku, spark-java

I've been trying to set the command to start my Java Spark application for Heroku. It says that the main class couldn't be found or loaded. I've tried many variations of the command where I've modified the path and arguments, but to no avail. Any idea as to where the error might be from?

My Procfile looks like this:

```
web: java ~/build/classes/java/main/WeatherApp
```

The log from heroku when pushing to master:

```
2020-03-22T01:12:21.114237+00:00 heroku[web.1]: Starting process with command `java ~/build/classes/java/main/WeatherApp`
2020-03-22T01:12:23.789821+00:00 heroku[web.1]: Process exited with status 1
2020-03-22T01:12:23.803504+00:00 heroku[web.1]: State changed from starting to crashed
2020-03-22T01:12:23.621957+00:00 app[web.1]: Setting JAVA_TOOL_OPTIONS defaults based on dyno size. Custom settings will override them.
2020-03-22T01:12:23.625398+00:00 app[web.1]: Picked up JAVA_TOOL_OPTIONS: -Xmx300m -Xss512k -XX:CICompilerCount=2 -Dfile.encoding=UTF-8
2020-03-22T01:12:23.715167+00:00 app[web.1]: Error: Could not find or load main class .app.build.classes.java.main.WeatherApp
2020-03-22T01:12:26.000000+00:00 app[api]: Build succeeded
```

Answer (score 0):

You're missing the classpath for the command. The classpath is where java looks for your classes. You can use the `-cp` switch to provide a classpath. It depends on your build process where your classes are, but one example could be:

```
web: java -cp build/classes/ WeatherApp
```